# Ruby Kata Gem: Calculator

Tags: ruby, calculator

I've just completed the Calculator Kata in the Kata Gem and I was hoping for some feedback. Here's the Kata:

```
Calculator Kata
 Create a calculator that is initialized with a string expression
  - detail: The expression is of the form digits separated by commas: "1,2"
  - detail: The expression is accessed by a method named expr
  - detail: The expression can be reset for evaluation at any time without re-initializing
  - example: Calculator.new "1,2"

completed (Y|n): y

   Add Method
    Create an add method that sums the string expression
     - detail: The method will return the sum of the digits
     - detail: The expression can contain 0, 1 or 2 numbers
     - detail: Then empty string will return 0
     - example: "" computes to 0
     - example: "1" computes to 1
     - example: "1,2" computes to 3

completed (Y|n):

  Allow the expression to contain an unknown amount of numbers
     - example: "1,2,3" computes to 6
     - example: "1,2,5,8" computes to 16

completed (Y|n):

Diff Method
  Create a diff method that computes the consecutive differences
     - detail: The expression must contain at least 2 digits
     - example: "1,0" compues to 1
     - example: "3,2,1" computes to 0
     - example: "5,4,3,2,1" computes to -5
     - detail: Expressions with less than 2 digits raise an exception
     - example: "" or "5"

completed (Y|n):

Prod Method
  Create a prod method that computes the multiples in the expression
     - detail: The method will return the product of the numbers
     - example: "0" computes to 0
     - example: "2,1" computes to 2
     - example: "3,2,1" computes to 6

completed (Y|n):

Div Method
  Create a div method that computes the consecutive divisions in the expression
     - detail: The method will return the final quotient of the numbers
     - detail: it will raise an exception if the expression contains the number 0
     - example: "2,1" computes to 2
     - example: "3,2,1" computes to 1
     - example: "1,2,3" computes to 0

completed (Y|n):



Congratulations!
- Create a calculator that is initialized with a string expression         01:15:02
- Create an add method that sums the string expression                     14:34:41
- Allow the expression to contain an unknown amount of numbers             00:04:33 
- Create a diff method that computes the consecutive differences           00:06:14
- Create a prod method that computes the multiples in the expression       00:20:07
- Create a div method that computes the consecutive divisions in the exp   00:11:54
----------------------------------------------------------------------     --------
Total Time taking Calculator kata:                                         16:32:31
```

And, here is my solution (specs and the Calculator class are in the same file):

```
class Calculator
  def initialize(expression="")
    @expression = expression.split(",").map(&:to_i) || 0
    if !@expression.any?
      @expression = [0]
    end
  end

  def expr
    @expression
  end

  def sum
    @expression.inject(&:+) || 0
  end

  def diff
    if @expression.compact.count < 2
      raise "expect 2 or more elements but recieved #{@expression.compact.count}"
    end
    @expression.inject(&:-)
  end

  def prod
    @expression.inject(&:*)
  end

  def div
    if @expression.find { |element| element == 0 }
      raise "divide by zero"
    end
    @expression.inject(&:/)
  end
end

describe "Calculator" do
  subject(:calculator) { Calculator.new(expression) }

  shared_examples "methods" do
    specify { expect { calculator }.to_not raise_exception }

    it { should respond_to(:expr) }
    it { should respond_to(:sum)  }
    it { should respond_to(:diff) }
    it { should respond_to(:prod) }
    it { should respond_to(:div)  }
  end

  shared_examples "too few elements" do
    specify { expect { calculator.diff }.to raise_exception }
  end

  shared_examples "divide by zero" do
    specify { expect { calculator.div }.to raise_exception }
  end

  context "with argument ''" do
    let(:expression) { "" }

    it_behaves_like "methods"
    it_behaves_like "too few elements"
    it_behaves_like "divide by zero"

    its(:expr) { should eq([0]) }
    its(:sum)  { should eq(0)   }
    its(:prod) { should eq(0)   }
  end

  context "with argument '1'" do
    let(:expression) { "1" }

    it_behaves_like "methods"
    it_behaves_like "too few elements"

    its(:expr) { should eq([1]) }
    its(:sum)  { should eq(1)   }
    its(:prod) { should eq(1)   }
  end

  context "with argument '1,2'" do
    let(:expression) { "1,2" }

    it_behaves_like "methods"

    its(:expr) { should eq([1,2]) }
    its(:sum)  { should eq(3)     }
    its(:diff) { should eq(-1)    }
    its(:prod) { should eq(2)     }
  end

  context "with argument '1,2,3," do
    let(:expression) { "1,2,3" }

    it_behaves_like "methods"

    its(:expr) { should eq([1,2,3]) }
    its(:sum)  { should eq(6)       }
    its(:diff) { should eq(-4)      }
    its(:prod) { should eq(6)       }
    its(:div)  { should eq(0)       }
  end

  context "with argument '1,2,5,8'" do
    let(:expression) { "1,2,5,8" }

    it_behaves_like "methods"

    its(:expr) { should eq([1,2,5,8]) }
    its(:sum)  { should eq(16)        }
    its(:diff) { should eq(-14)       }
    its(:prod) { should eq(80)        }
  end

  context "with argument '1,0'" do
    let(:expression) { "1,0" }

    it_behaves_like "divide by zero"

    its(:diff) { should eq(1) }
    its(:prod) { should eq(0) }
  end

  context "with argument '3,2,1'" do
    let(:expression) { "3,2,1" }

    its(:diff) { should eq(0)   }
    its(:prod) { should eq(6)   }
    its(:div)  { should eq(1) }
  end

  context "with argument '5,4,3,2,1,'" do
    let(:expression) { "5,4,3,2,1" }

    its(:diff) { should eq(-5)  }
    its(:prod) { should eq(120) }
  end

  context "with arguments '2,1'" do
    let(:expression) { "2,1" }

    its(:div) { should eq(2) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good! Most importantly, you're using `inject` properly. The specs seem nice too (although running all the `"methods"` expectations every time is maybe a little redundant).

But I don't see support for this requirement:

> The expression can be reset for evaluation at any time without re-initializing

Right now, you only have a reader method for `expr`.
Also, that reader returns an array - not the original string. While it's not stated directly, I think it's implied that you should get a string back. `calculator.expr = calculator.expr` should be idempotent.

There's also something weird going on in your current `initialize` method:

```
@expression = expression.split(",").map(&:to_i) || 0
```

I don't see how it would ever get to the `OR` (`split` will either give you an empty array or raise an exception), but even if it did, it'd just raise an exception in the next line:

```
if !@expression.any?
```

since Fixnum doesn't respond to `any?`.

But it wouldn't take much to fix all of this. Something like this should be OK

```
class Calculator
  attr_reader :expr

  def expr=(string='')
    @expr = string
    @expression = @expr.split(",").map(&:to_i)
    @expression = [0] if @expression.none?
  end

  alias_method :initialize, :expr=

  #...
end
```

But I'd probably rename `@expression` to `@values` or something, just to make the separation clearer (and to give the array a pluralized name).

The `div` method can be made simpler, as this

```
 if @expression.find { |element| element == 0 }
```

can be expressed as just:

```
 if @expression.include?(0)
```

And lastly, you may want to raise the built-in `ZeroDivisionError` instead of a custom one:

```
 raise ZeroDivisionError if @expression.include?(0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. This is really very helpful.

Comment: @user341493 No prob. Don't forget to click the checkmark to mark your question as answered (no rush though)